# Formulário reativo Input com matInput

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Implementei um campo input text que busca os elementos em uma lista, esse funcionamento está correto, porém ao digitar as palavras ele não permite espaços em nomes compostos que já estão encontrados na lista, como se forçasse a seleção do mesmo. É possível desabilitar esse comportamento e permitir livre inserção e digitação de elementos, tentei remover o binding do form control, mas dessa forma ele perde a busca.

***CAMPO INPUT***

```
<input matInput placeholder="{{'INTERPOLAÇÃO }}" [formControl]="filterControl" [maxLength]="255">
```

***DECLARAÇÃO DE VARIÁVEL NO FORMULÁRIO***

```
filterControl = new FormControl();
```

***FUNÇÃO***

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.filteredOptions = this.filterControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith<string | GenericFilter[]>(''),
      map((value) => (typeof value === 'string' ? value : this.lastFilter)),
      map((filter) => this.filter(filter))
    );
  }
```

Comment: Não deu pra entender muito bem o que está acontecendo. Pode melhorar a explicação, ou fazer uma simulação lá no StackBlitz?

Comment: Creio que estava bem explicado já, mas foi resolvido implementando um timeout no formulário, assim quando se abre normal com um '.open' ele habilita o autofocus no campo input do form reativo. Obrigado.